# Reach the count of joined objects (sub-query) in the View in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In the Index page that shows all offers, I am trying to get the count number of all customers joined to each specific offer, I am use below in the view :

Joined Customers : @item.OfferCustomerTBLs.Count()

But it return me error :
Value cannot be null.

So, Please inform me how to use the count of joined objects of customers, and when null show nothing ?

Comment: What is `@item` here ?

Comment: is come from : 
foreach (var item in Model) {

Comment: so it should be `item.OfferCustomerTBLs.Count()`. And if OfferCustomerTBLs is a list it should `item.OfferCustomerTBLs.Count`

Answer (score 0):

The problem were in Controller, I have to include the joined objects as :

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
  return View(offersTBLs.Include(y=>y.OfferCustomerTBLs).ToList());
   }
```

Thanks for all who tried to help and Thank you Mairaj Ahmad